# Core-Plot : y Axis labels should start from 60

Tags: ios, core-plot, scatter-plot

I need to draw a scatter plot, in which the x axis should intersect with y axis at (0,60).
I also need interval of 20 on the y Axis.

The problems I am facing right now are:

1. y axis is starting from 0
2. The gap between y axis labels example, from 60 - 80 is too much.

What I have done so far:

To set the intersection points:

> > > > *x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromString(@"60");*

To set the major tick locations:

```
NSSet *majorTickLocations = [NSSet setWithObjects:[NSDecimalNumber zero],
     [NSDecimalNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:60],
     [NSDecimalNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:80],
     [NSDecimalNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:100],
     [NSDecimalNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:120],
     nil];

y.majorTickLocations = majorTickLocations;
```

Any pointer in the direction will be helpful.

Regards,
Ishan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the axes cross at (0, 60), set the `orthogonalCoordinateDecimal` of each axis:

```
x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromDouble(60.0);
y.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromDouble(0.0);
```

The axis labeling policy determines how the tick marks and labels are positioned. If you are providing the tick and label positions yourself (`CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone`), you can put them anywhere you want. See the "Axis Labeling Policies" demo in the *Plot Gallery* example app for samples of each available labeling policy.